# How to filter docker containers in exited status using docker_host_info?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-machine, ansible-2.x, dockerpy

Is there any other ansible-docker module to capture all the containers on the VM even the ones in exited status.

```
 - name: Get container info
    docker_host_info:
      containers: yes
    register: result
```

docker_host_info captures the containers only in UP status. Is there a way to capture or filter the ones in exited status. Kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make use of [containers_filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_host_info_module.html#parameter-containers_filters) option with a filter `status=exited`.

Check this ansible playbook:

```
---
- name: First playbook
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Get container info
    docker_host_info:
      containers: yes
      containers_filters:
        status: "exited"
    register: result
  - debug:
      msg: "Exited container list : {{ item['Names'] }}"
    loop: "{{ result.containers }}"
```

I have few exited container on my VM.

```
[centos@jumphost tmp]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES
b2dacc3e5d04        httpd               "httpd-foreground"       6 minutes ago       Exited (137) 6 minutes ago                       goofy_noyce
f54e2aa1c510        alpine              "/bin/sh"                44 minutes ago      Exited (0) 44 minutes ago                        dazzling_noyce
db7789d302db        <no image>          "/bin/sh -c 'touch /…"   2 days ago          Created                                          fervent_morse
3e948852f5cb        <no image>          "/bin/sh -c 'touch /…"   2 days ago          Created                                          goofy_wiles
[centos@jumphost tmp]$
```

Run the ansible playbook:

```
[centos@jumphost tmp]$ sudo ansible-playbook -c local -i 127.0.0.1 a.yaml 
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /var/tmp/127.0.0.1 as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [First playbook] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [Get container info] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'Status': u'Exited (137) 10 minutes ago', u'Command': u'httpd-foreground', u'Names': [u'/goofy_noyce'], u'Created': 1596717162, u'Image': u'httpd', u'Ports': [], u'Id': u'b2dacc3e5d048f6ae4143e0b76931f104d1dc132e81d378b2456aa5839e459a6'}) => {
    "msg": "Exited container list : [u'/goofy_noyce']"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'Status': u'Exited (0) About an hour ago', u'Command': u'/bin/sh', u'Names': [u'/dazzling_noyce'], u'Created': 1596714877, u'Image': u'alpine', u'Ports': [], u'Id': u'f54e2aa1c510ece29d8665c65ae5de29552e7e280e7591c399a57a976f80fa81'}) => {
    "msg": "Exited container list : [u'/dazzling_noyce']"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

[centos@jumphost tmp]$
```

As you can see only the exited containers are getting listed.

**Update:**

To list both running and exited container use multiple ansible task.

```
Task 1:
- name: Get exited container info
    |
containers_filters:
        status: "exited"
    |
Task 2
- name: Get running container info
    |
containers_filters:
        status: "running"
```

Comment: How to get all the docker containers...one which is running up and in exited status.
I tried status: all throws me error. Could you please help.

`containers_filters:
        status: "all"`

Comment: @SaraJames I can't fins a way to list both running and exited container in one go. You need multiple ansible task to achieve it. Check my updated answer.

Comment: you're awesome!! thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: @SaraJames Great! Can you mark the answer as accepted so that others can know it is successfully answered.